# Move hard drive without using sysprep?

Tags: windows-8.1, sysprep

I have a broken PC running Windows 8.1 which wont start anymore - it's just a PSU problem. I do have a some other hardware which I could move the hard disks to.

Because I can't power the original PC, I can't run sysprep - so is it safe enough to just move the disks without using sysprep? Is there anything to be aware of?

UPDATE: This is just a bare bones install of Windows via an MSDN licence - it doesn't have the traditional myriad of 3rd party software installed on it like new PCs.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you not move the PSU over?

Comment: Start in safe mode after installing it in new PC, then run sysprep while in safe mode, reboot.

Comment: @Jonno - +1 for lateral thinking. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 and later are pretty robust regarding hardware changes.

All you should have to do is plugging it in and booting, preferably using the boot drive only for the start.

Make a backup of the disk just to be sure.

Windows should notice running of a different board and update drivers accordingly, especially if the new board uses a similar chip set (e.g. nForce to nforce). Not that this will invalidate your license activation.

If that process fails, Windows will show a BSOD, in which case you should be able to boot and repair using a disk image.

**Edit:** If it's really just the PSU, I'd only replace that. :)